# App for only apple watch not for the phone

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-push-notifications, apple-watch

I've recently been given a project at work and can't seem to find much help on this. I've got 2 questions. But context might help. Also if you able to only answer one question I'd still greatly appreciate it

I have to create an Apple watch app that allows you to receive a notification when someone clicks a button on another one of our programs. Now I've been able to do this with an Android phone using Firebase cloud messaging using flutter dart.

1. Is it possible to create an app just for the apple watch, I know the watch is tied to the phone but am wanting to know if it is possible to make an exclusive app for the watch.
2. What resources am would I need to develop in the apple environment. I'm currently using an old thinkpad with Linux. Do I need to get an apple laptop and watch for this project or is there anyway around this?

I've been able to do this with an Android phone using Firebase cloud messaging using flutter dart. But now I need to know what I need to get so I dont waste money on things I dont need